# 7' x 7' Resin Shed Base - Plywood on blocks?

Tags: wood, plywood, wood-selection, outdoor

I bought a 7x7 resin shed. Link below: https://www.menards.com/main/outdoors/sheds-outdoor-storage-accessories/sheds/suncast-reg-covington-reg-storage-shed-7-x-7/bms7725/p-1507530514920.htm

I need to build a base for it, I would really rather not spend $100 on 2x6's to build the base, but I don't trust a fully gravel/paver base. Could I simply put some cheap pavers directly on the ground (around 8 inches apart), and put the plywood on top of that and have the plastic floor of the shed screw directly into the plywood. This would give my shed a ridgid wood floor (underneath the plastic) and still give the plywood lift off the dirt.

Crazy idea?

Comment: I don't think this Q is really is a good fit for the Woodworking SE, even though it does peripherally relate to woodworking. And anyway you'll likely get much better feedback on the Home Improvement SE. My 2c, you won't get away with pavers on dirt, pavers or concrete blocks directly on the ground as a base for a shed is something that's notorious for not being stable enough in the long term (although local soil conditions are probably key here). Slab, fairly deep gravel/hardcore bed or concrete footings are really the only good options I believe.

Comment: One other thing, just in case nobody else says it, you should look into using OSB instead of ply for a few reasons.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the wrong forum. That was good info though.

Answer (score 1):

I used cinder blocks, buried but standing about 4 " above the soil.I layed treated 2 X 4 on the cinder block with no anchoring ( no wind concern). I spill a lot of water so I made floor of house brick , no mortar. It has worked well for 15 years.